# Boot linux kernel on cpu1

Tags: linux-kernel, bootloader

I am trying to boot linux kernel on cpu1.

For this was written small bootloader that copy real mode part to 0x10200 and protected mode part to 0x100000, than just did jump (on cpu1) to 0x10200.
And got next error:

```
[    0.001000] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K (ffffffff8200a000 - ffffffff82012000)
[    0.001000] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=0 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.001000] ..MP-BIOS bug: 8254 timer not connected to IO-APIC
[    0.001000] ...trying to set up timer (IRQ0) through the 8259A ...
[    0.001000] ..... (found apic 0 pin 0) ...
[    0.001000] ....... failed.
[    0.001000] ...trying to set up timer as Virtual Wire IRQ...
[    0.001000] ..... failed.
[    0.001000] ...trying to set up timer as ExtINT IRQ...
[    0.002000] ..... failed :(.
[    0.002000] Kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work!  Boot with apic=debug and send a report.  Then try booting with the 'noapic' option.
[    0.002000] 
[    0.002000] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.1.27+ #52
[    0.002000] Hardware name:  , BIOS Bochs 01/01/2007
[    0.002000]  0000000000000000 ffff88001e8dbd28 ffffffff818c4a73 ffffffff81ba8888
[    0.002000]  0000000000000008 ffff88001e8dbda8 ffffffff818c1231 ffff88001e8dbd48
[    0.002000]  ffffffff00000008 ffff88001e8dbdb8 ffff88001e8dbd58 ffffffff81f24ee1
[    0.002000] Call Trace:
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff818c4a73>] dump_stack+0x4d/0x63
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff818c1231>] panic+0xb6/0x1e4
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff81f24ee1>] ? timer_irq_works+0x28/0x57
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff81f25acf>] setup_IO_APIC+0x56c/0x71a
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff81f247e1>] apic_bsp_setup+0x87/0x96
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff81f229dc>] native_smp_prepare_cpus+0x232/0x270
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff81f1507e>] kernel_init_freeable+0x91/0x21a
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff818be210>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff818be219>] kernel_init+0x9/0xf0
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff818cee52>] ret_from_fork+0x42/0x70
[    0.002000]  [<ffffffff818be210>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    0.002000] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work!  Boot with apic=debug and send a report.  Then try booting with the 'noapic' option.
[    0.002000]
```

Is it some limitation for running linux kernel on other cpu (in my case cpu1) except cpu0?

Comment: How do you distinguish CPU number? I mean how you be sure that the same core is being used always as CPU 0?

Comment: I just got smp processor id of CPU. Something like: int cpu = smp_processor_id();

Comment: Yeah, my question does 0 means really CPU core 0 in *hardware*? My understanding that 0 is just a reference to a first started CPU core on the system and thus I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do, and although I don't understand why exactly, I can imagine you want to run some realtime code on cpu0 and want to have Linux run on cpu1 or more. You will have to compile a kernel with SMP disabled or otherwise modified to account for your already initialized CPUs. Then you would need to configure the APIC to raise the Programmable Interval Timer on CPU1, as well as all other interrupts. This could be a small edit to a source file for a dirty hack, or you can get something like irqbalance and use the source to assign IRQs to your Linux-initialized CPUs. Finally, you are unlikely to be able to use certain features like hypervisor functionality, bios vesa drivers, etc.

The more common approach to what you may be trying to do is to get Linux to not initialize a core at the end, and then manually init it with kernel code. Since your code or even a realtime OS is much less complex than the Linux kernel, it's better to let Linux be first. If you really need to be first, consider booting another CPU and let it run your code and then jump into Linux with CPU0. Realtime Linux patches use the former method (last core for realtime). If you initialize it first, numbering shouldn't matter as commented on your question.